# How do I fix assembly/file dependency runtime error, for c# solution?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a plugin for Hearthstone Deck Tracker. I followed the instructions on their github repo https://github.com/HearthSim/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/wiki/Creating-Plugins. I had a proto-type working but I want to support audio fading. To do this I need a 3rd party library. I went with nAudio. I installed it via the package manager using `Install-Package NAudio -Version 1.10.0`

Building succeeded. (I am building a solution). However upon running it via Hearthstone Deck Tracker the plugin gives a binding error. I saw other posts about fuslogvw.exe, so I made sure to run that. It gave me a more detailed error message but I still don't understand how to fix it.

Here is the full error message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NAudio, Version=1.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'NAudio, Version=1.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at HsBgSongPlayer.Class1Plugin.OnLoad()
   at Hearthstone_Deck_Tracker.Plugins.PluginWrapper.Load() in D:\a\Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker\Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker\Hearthstone Deck Tracker\Plugins\PluginWrapper.cs:line 93

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\HearthstoneDeckTracker\app-1.13.15\HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = NAudio, Version=1.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : HsBgSongPlayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\HearthstoneDeckTracker\app-1.13.15\HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/NAudio.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/NAudio/NAudio.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/NAudio.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/NAudio/NAudio.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/Plugins/NAudio.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/Plugins/NAudio/NAudio.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/Plugins/NAudio.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/aless/AppData/Local/HearthstoneDeckTracker/app-1.13.15/Plugins/NAudio/NAudio.EXE.
```

Just in case it matters, here is a code snippet that causes the error. It was pulled from the nAudio sample code for testing.

```
using System.Threading;
using NAudio.Wave;
...
...
public void OnLoad()
{
  using (var mf = new MediaFoundationReader(Class1.link_gga))
  using (var wo = new WaveOutEvent())
  {
      wo.Init(mf);
      wo.Play();
      while (wo.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
      {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
   }
...
...
```

I am very new to this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: The solution is simply that I have to copy the nAudio.dll to the plugins folder where myPlugin.dll exists.

Comment: most likely the version you installed is different in your web.conig/app.config file. Check the version you installed vs whats listed in your config file.

Comment: @Jawad I see in VS code that my nAudio installed and version are both 1.10.0. I have a packages.config file,
it contains the correct version. Perhaps the targetVersion is incorrect and causes the error?

Comment: Check the properties of the dll in references and make sure it is set to true for copylocal

Comment: @Jawad Yes, the NAudio reference has Copy Local set to true. If I copy the nAudio.dll to the same folder as the plugin it works. However, I'd like it to be packaged within my .dll file

Comment: There is no such thing as packaging a dll inside another dll. You have to copy all the referenced dlls to make your process work

Comment: Thank you. I will close this issue.